# SWT Table - Checkbox / Highlight Listeners

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, listener, highlight

I have a SWT Table with check boxes enable on the rows to allow TableItems to be selected. I currently have a listener on there

```
myTable.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event selectionEvent) {}});
```

This listener fires both when a check box for a row is checked and when a row is highlighted / selected, I haven't been able to find a way to separate these actions. Am I using the wrong listener or is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check within the `Listener` if it's a checkbox event or a selection event:

```
myTable.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        if(e.detail == SWT.CHECK)
        {
            // Checkbox
        }
        else
        {
            // Selection
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for asking what now seems like a ridiculous question.